# Integral of $\frac{1}{\cos x +1}$ by integation by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I know you can integrate this function by multiplying by the conjugate but I was experimenting a bit and tried to integrate it by parts, It doesnt work but I dont know why.

Here's my procces:

$\int{\frac{1}{\cos x +1}dx}=^*\frac{x}{\cos x +1}+\int{\frac{-\sin x}{(\cos x +1)^2}dx}=^{**}\frac{x}{\cos x +1} +\int{\frac{du}{u^2}}=\frac{x}{\cos x +1}-\frac{1}{u}+C$

$=\frac{x}{\cos x +1}-\frac{1}{\cos x +1}$

*: Integration by parts $f'=1;g=\frac{1}{\cos x +1}$

**: u-Substitution $u=\cos x +1;du=-\sin x dx$

That function do not differentiate to $\frac{1}{\cos x+1}$ so is not an antiderivative. Probably I did something illegal in my procces that's why i'm asking here.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I see the mistake now I forgot the x term, how silly of me. Well, thanks for everyone who pointed it out to me :D!

Comment: Integration by parts is not the best method here. Your second integral actually becomes harder than the original.

Comment: Integration by parts is used to the life easier.  But applying to this integral will make the life more difficult!  You better use double-angle formula to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a mistake. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\cos x +1} \, dx &= \frac{x}{\cos x +1}-\int \frac{x\sin x}{(\cos x+1)^2}\, dx \\ &= \frac{x}{\cos x +1}+\int \frac{\cos^{-1}{(u-1)}}{u^2} \, du
\end{aligned}$$

It is easy to see that this approach leads nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

The very first step is wrong. You missed a factor of $x$ in the second term.

Answer (score 0):

For this integral, integration by parts make the life more difficult. We can use double-angle formula as below:
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{d x}{\cos x+1} \\
=& \int \frac{d x}{2 \cos ^{2} \frac{x}{2}} \\
=& \int \sec ^{2} \frac{x}{2} d\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \\
=& \tan \frac{x}{2}+C
\end{aligned}